Unity Character Controller's colliders are not colliding with normal colliders
In Unity the CharacterControler colliders are colliding with each other, normal colliders are colliding with each other but CharacterController colliders are not colliding with normal colliders.
All layers are Default and I checked:
edit > project settings > physics2D > layer collision matrix
and they are all ticked.
Player only have character controller.
Ground has box collider (also tried to add dynamic / kinematic / static rb2D to ground. It didn't work).(player dont have rigidbody I know it shouldnt)
I am using _controller.Move(move + _velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime); in FixedUpdate.
_velocity is for gravity. It's not fast yet, its slow, but just goes through the ground.
I also tried in a different project and it didn't work.

CharacterController doesn't interact with 2D colliders.

Note that Physics and Physics2D are two completely unrelated separate engines and don't know / affect each other. CharacterController is a 3D collider and only "knows" about Physics and none of the 2D components

This thread may be related:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/proper-collision-detection-with-charactercontroller.292598/
Also according to the documentation here:
"A CharacterController is not affected by forces and will only move when you call the Move function. It will then carry out the movement but be constrained by collisions."
It looks like the movement of the character controller can be constrained by collisions, but forces acting on it must be done manually.
It might be worth trying to encapsulate the character in a standard box collider, or capsule collider, to account for the force of the ground.
